# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Unmanaged Memory

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, memory

My development team is using ASP.NET Core 3.1.20 with Angular 10.2. We are seeing a large amount of unmanaged memory being consumed and never released. We are simulating load via a simple locust script with 200 concurrent users. I initially speculated that this was logic error in our code that was never releasing memory but I am not starting to wonder if it is something to do with how Microsoft manages memory. I have tried setting the false setting as well. This does help with overall memory but I can still expose the same problem regardless over time. I have verified that my code is purely managed code via ILDASM and PEVerify.

Any help is greatly appreciated

[Application Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh5w4.png)

Comment: are you sure you Disposed all [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0) objects?

Comment: yes however I will re-review that just in case. Thanks for the feedback!